# ZEND - Issue with download file (encoding, not able to open downloaded file)

Tags: zend-framework, download, view-helpers

I made a download form in my project, but problem is when i download the file and im trying to open it, Zend renderer is adding to it my layout html code... I read that i have to disable renderer and layout. But the problem is tjat i have to do this in my own helper, not in controller file, cause i need to have download in that helper file. 
My download function is something like this:

```
<?php
class Zend_View_Helper_EditArticles extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function EditArticles()
    {
        //some code here, getting data from db table

        //and now the download
        if (isset($_POST['downloadarticle' . $i])) {
            //this is probably bad and its not working as it should
            //(?)Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);
            //(?)Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('layout')->disableLayout();

            $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/articles/';
            $file = $articles->GetArticleToDownload($_POST['art_id' . $i]);

            $name = $file['name'];
            $path = $file['path'];
            $getfile = str_replace('//', '/', $targetPath) . $path . '.pdf';
            $size = $file['size'];

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name.pdf");
            header("Content-length: $size");
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            readfile($getfile);
            break;
        }
    }

echo $this->view->partial('/index/index.phtml','EditArticles');
```

And when I download the PDF, Adobe Reader can't open it (when I download other files they can't be opened either). I opened them with notepad and before the PDF content there was a lot of HTML layout code... What am I doing wrong?

In Adobe Reader I get this message:

> Adobe Reader could not open 'filename.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Answer (score 1):

That code does not belong in a view helper. It belongs in the controller or maybe an *action* helper.

Something like this in your controller should work:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

// ...

$this->getResponse()
    ->setHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer', true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf', true) // change to application/pdf
    ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename={$name}.pdf", true)
    ->setHeader('Content-length', $size, true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true)
    ->appendBody(readfile($getfile));
```

Comment: ok but if i put it in my main controller file it will disable the view of all my application :) the fancy trick is that i'm using helpers instead controllers in modules which can be put in any place of website and layout is rendered by other controler and download action is also in other in this case helper instead controller (of module). Anyway i decided to create a download controller and passing id of file to download by $_GET method to it and do all download in that controller and it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The following 2 lines of code should accomplish what you need and do it in a fashion that works from anywhere in your Zend application.

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('noViewRenderer', true);
```

Comment: its not working as i expect to when i put it in my helper file :) i think that the prolem is that i render layout in other controller and downloading file in other odule also in other in this case helper insted of controller and disabling layout here don't disable the main controller layout